# Iterator erase called before return?

Tags: c++, iterator, erase

I'm working with the EyeTab code available on [Github](https://github.com/errollw/EyeTab/tree/master/EyeTab_SP2). I've been chasing down bad output values, and right before the function below returns the vector I need, there is a call to iterator *::erase* which removes all the values and returns a bogus vector. I'd appreciate any help figuring out what is going on here!

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> randomSubset(const std::vector<T>& src, typename std::vector<T>::size_type size) {

if (size > src.size())
    throw std::range_error("Subset size out of range");

std::vector<T> ret;
std::set<int> vals;

for (size_t j = src.size() - size; j < src.size(); ++j) {

    int rand = random(0, j); // generate a random integer in range [0, j]

    if (vals.find(rand) == vals.end())
        ret.push_back(src[rand]);
    else
        ret.push_back(src[j]);
}
//the value for ret is correct here, but it is not being returned, why?
//why is iterator erase being called here and clearing out this value?
return ret;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the vector is bogus?

Comment: `if (vals.find(rand) == vals.end())` will always be true, because `vals` is an empty vector.  Also, your result won't necessarily be a subset, because a value from `src` can be chosen more than once.  And your output will be biased, because the first element of `src` has `size` chances to be chosen, while the last element only has one chance.

Comment: You need to show the actual code that includes the erase() call that you claim is related. The code above is technically okay, although it suffers from various issues as GWW and nix already pointed out.

Comment: Looks like [Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is inherited code, so I'm working on removing some of the logic errors, thank you for listing them out. When I step into the line `code` return ret; `code` I end up in this: `code` iterator erase(const_iterator _First, const_iterator _Last)
  { // erase [_First, _Last)
  if (_First == begin() && _Last == end())
   { // erase all
   clear();
   return (begin());
   }
  else
   { // partial erase, one at a time
   while (_First != _Last)
    erase(_First++);
   return (iterator(_First._Ptr, this));
   }
  } `code`

Comment: Walked through it again and I can see that "randomSubset returned" is the correct vector, but for some reason it is not getting saved to the vector I am using: `code` std::vector<cv::Point2f> sample = randomSubset(edgePoints, 5); `code`